# Generating UIDs in a multi-instance and multi-threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, azure, guid, high-availability

I'm trying to generate unique IDs for pieces of content and users in Windows Azure. I'm in a web role service with 3 instances (and the IIS handlers are of course multithreaded).

How can I generate unique identifiers made up of only digits and storable in 10 digits or less? A degree of randomness to these numbers would be good.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [SnowMaker](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/07/14/released-snowmaker-a-unique-id-generator-for-azure-or-any-other-cloud-hosting-environment/). I haven't used it myself, but it seems like a sound approach. Note that it will produce gaps in the IDs and "waste" some IDs. With 10 digits you'll have ~10 billions possible IDs, so that may or may not be a problem for you.